# Удаление бинарного дерева в С++

Tags: бинарное-дерево, c++

Помогите найти утечку памяти в следующей реализации бинарного дерева. Может кому не лень копаться в таком куске кода)

```
template <typename T>
class Node
{
 private:
    T data;
    Node<T> *left, *right;
    bool flag;
    friend class Tree<T>;
 public:
    Node(): flag(false), left(NULL), right(NULL){}
    ~Node{if(left) delete left; if(right)delete right}
};

template <typename T>
class Tree
{
 private:
    Node<T>* head;
    Node<T>* AddNode(Node<T>*, T);
    void ViewTree(Node<T>*);
    void DestroyTree(Node<T>*);
 public:
    Tree();
    ~Tree();
    void View();
    void Add(T);
};

template <typename T>
Tree<T>::Tree(): head(NULL){}

template <typename T>
Tree<T>::~Tree()
{
 DestroyTree(head);
}

template <typename T>
void Tree<T>::View()
{
 ViewTree(head);
}

template <typename T>
void Tree<T>::Add(T obj)
{
 head = AddNode(head, obj);
}

template <typename T>
Node<T>* Tree<T>::AddNode(Node<T>* root, T obj)
{
 if(root == NULL)
 {
  root = new Node<T>;
  root->data = obj;
  root->flag = true;
 }
 else
 {
  if(obj < root->data)
  {
   root->left = AddNode(root->left, obj);
  } 
  else 
  {
   root->right = AddNode(root->right, obj);
  }
 }
 return root;
}

template <typename T>
void Tree<T>::ViewTree(Node<T> *root)
{
 if(root->left)
 {
  ViewTree(root->left);
 }
 if(root->flag) cout << root->data << endl;
 if(root->right)
 {
  ViewTree(root->right);
 }
}

template <typename T>
void Tree<T>::DestroyTree(Node<T> *root)
{
 if(root)
 {
  DestroyTree(root->left);
  DestroyTree(root->right);
  delete root;
 }
}

int main()
{
 Tree<int> *tree = new Tree<int>;
 tree->Add(5);
 tree->Add(4);
 tree->Add(2);
 tree->View();
 delete tree;
}
```

Спасибо, если кому не лень в этом копаться

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tree<T>::DestroyTree пробегает по дереву но не делает delete